# where can i find XFS API reference and samples?

Tags: cen-xfs

I wanna work with CEN/XFS (Extensions for Financial Services), possibly in C#.NET.

could anyone tell me how and where can i find XFS last release API reference and samples?

and does .NET framework have classes & tools for XFS?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey. I found the documentation and API reference: http://www.cen.eu/cen/Sectors/Sectors/ISSS/CEN%20Workshop%20Agreements/Pages/CWA15748.aspx ,  but still have the question: does .NET framework have classes & tools for XFS , or i should call APIs?